# How can I remap Caps Lock to AltGR on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, keyboard

I've tried SharpKey, but it doesn't recognize, and KeyMapper, but it seems to have no effect at all; not sure why. How can I make Caps Lock behave like Alt GR?

Comment: The "duplicate" question here no longer has a usable answer.

Answer (score 1):

1) Create a registry file (text with `.reg` suffix):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,1d,00,3a,00,00,00,00,00
```

2) Try via powershell,

```
$hexified = "00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,1d,00,3a,00,00,00,00,00".Split(',') | % { "0x$_"}

$kbLayout = 'HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout'

New-ItemProperty -Path $kbLayout -Name "Scancode Map" -PropertyType Binary -Value ([byte[]]$hexified)
```

Comment: This works execpt that, on Windows 10, it turns capslock into "Control" key. Replace the hex code with `00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,38,e0,3a,00,00,00,00,00` and everything will be fine.

Comment: @MehdiSadeghi your suggestion made it into alt for me